# Creating own XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlhttprequest, signing

I have wrote program for xml signing. I added some **HashDataInfo** elements which are described in https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/,but there is no description for them in https://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2/XAdES.xsd , so when I am validating xml document against that schema, it shows exception (Invalid **HashDataInfo** element).
I have added in XAdES.xsd schema description for HashDataInfo,and now everything is good.
My question is.
Is it legal or not? Can I have some problems in future? Or I just can edit xml schemas and there will be no problems with standard?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is "legal" or not depends on the licensing conditions.

Whether it will give you problems in future: well, it depends. Departing from standards to do your own thing sometimes pays off and sometimes doesn't. This isn't really a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I only want to know, what if I add HashDataInfo schema in XAdES.xsd , because it's described in their page,but in schema not